# help with leg_detection

Tags: ros, leg-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on leg_detection using [this](http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector?distro=indigo). I am using Ubuntu 14.04, ros-Indigo, with a turtlebot. whenever i run:

> roslaunch leg_detector leg_detector.launch

I am getting the following error:

> [ WARN] [1466630966.002926837]: MessageFilter [target=odom_combined ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.leg_detector.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.

I did go through the old questions related to this error and changes my fixed_frame from:

> odom_comined to odom

when i changed my fixed frame and ran:

> rostopic echo /camera_tracker_measurements

it outputs nothing. can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237819/help-with-leg_detection/) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're listening to the wrong topics. Look here for the proper outputs: http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0